# RabbitMQ Web Interface - doesn't show queue until queue read?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a Powershell that sends a message to Rabbit-MQ. I've seen the same from BizTalk.  The new queue name does not show up on the web interface until a message is retrieved from that queue at least one time.   Is this the normal process?  I don't understand why it wouldn't show up as soon as data was written to it.

Similar, I seem to be noticing that I can't store records in the queue until it is read once.  I'm sending to an exchange with a routing key.  If I write a program and send 5 messages there, the queue doesn't show up in RabbitMQ.  But once I create a program to read/listen to that queue, from then on it shows up with the count of messages.

Sample Powershell Code:

```
Import-Module PSRabbitMQ

Set-RabbitMQConfig -ComputerName localhost 

$User = "myuser"
#The second command uses the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlet to create a secure string from a plain text password. The command uses the *AsPlainText* parameter to indicate that the string is plain text and the *Force* parameter to confirm that you understand the risks of using plain text.
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force

#The third command uses the New-Object cmdlet to create a **PSCredential** object from the values in the $User and $PWord variables.
$CredRabbit = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $PWord 


#Set some common parameters we will always use:
$Params = @{
        Credential = $CredRabbit
    }
$Exchange = "MyExchange"
$RoutingKey = "NealTest3"
$showDate = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date

$numMessagesPerRun = 5 
for ($j=1; $j -le $numMessagesPerRun; $j++) 
{
  $message = "Hello at date/time= $showDate " + $j 
  Write-Host "Message = $message" 
  Send-RabbitMQMessage -Exchange $Exchange -Key $RoutingKey -InputObject $message -vhost base -Persistent @Params
}

$showDate = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
Write-Host "Ended $showDate"
```

My Queue: NealTest3 will not show up when I do "rabbitmqctl list_queues -p base" until I run another Powershell to consume at least one message from that queue.

Code from second program to read the queue (left out the same logon info):

```
Start-RabbitMqListener -Exchange $Exchange `
                       -Key $QueueName `
                       -QueueName $QueueName `
                        -AutoDelete $false `
                       -vhost base `
                       @Params | % { 
    #$req = $_ | ConvertFrom-Json
    $req = $_ 
    $counter = $counter + 1 
    Write-Host $counter + " " + $req
    }
```

It reads the 5 messages I put there, even though the queue in theory didn't exist, according to the list_queues.

Comment: Whatever method is reading from the queue is following best practice by assertively declaring the queue first. However, you may want to scrutinize that behavior to see if it’s doing what you want.

Comment: Also, providing code is usually helpful to rule out other things which may be going on.

Comment: This is not code specific; We use BizTalk Server where we set up ReceivePorts and SendPorts and I've seen it there; then I reproduced the issue in Powershell. Our RabbitMQ adapter for BizTalk creates the queues on the fly.

Comment: So is this a BizTalk issue? Maybe add that tag?

Comment: No, this is not a BizTalk issue; as i said, I reproduced it with Powershell (actually before posting here). I'm assuming any language would do the same. Write to an exchange with a routing key.  I guess queue is not created until someone tries to read with that routing key?

Comment: No code is posted, so I have nothing but your word to go on... that being the case, no. A queue is created with a [Queue.Declare method](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare). There is no other way to create a queue (outside of the management tools).

Comment: This may be a bug with the management plug-in, which if that is the case, it was recently introduced. What happens when you use [`rabbitmqctl list_queues`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#list_queues)?

Comment: I posted code and update about list_queues, but I still say this is a conceptual question, not a coding question.

Comment: So, just to be clear, what you're saying is the following: 
1. connect to the server - 2. publish messages - 3. subscribe to the queue. When doing things in that precise order, and nothing else, the queue does not appear with messages in it until #3 happens? This is impossible as far as I can tell.

Comment: The appropriate behavior given the above is as follows:
1. When publishing to the broker, if the broker cannot route the message to a queue, the default behavior is to drop the message silently. *This behavior is highly configurable.*
2. When consuming from a queue, if the queue did not exist when the consumer was created, the behavior is to close the channel with `PRECONDITION_FAILED`. I do not believe this behavior can be changed.

Comment: Yes to the question.  I publish message, queue does not show up, I start the consumer, and it gets the messages that were being held somewhere, then the queue shows up in the list.  So the impossible is happening?  It seems odd to me, that's why I posted the question.  Using Release 3.6.14.  No messages are being "dropped silently".

Comment: It sure does sound like you've found an interesting bug... er... "feature" :) I will have to investigate and see if I can replicate it

Comment: Sorry, reported one thing wrong.  The records were being "dropped silently".  My receiver was printing 5 debug statements, and my mind mistakenly matched them to the 5 messages I was writing.  A guy I work with showed me what he does... He goes to the exchange, and then sets up the binding to the queue, before running the first program to store the messages.   You said "dropping silently" is configurable - can you point me to where?

Comment: The queue appears on the website as soon as I run the consumer program, even if it doesn't receive any messages immediately.